# List folders by modification time of children in linux?

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, shell

I have a folder, we'll call it `/scripts/`, that contains subfolders for a number of different scripts (let's say `/scripts/file_export`, `/scripts/record_ingest`, `/scripts/stats`).  Inside these folders are all kinds of things...shell scripts, perl scripts, ruby scripts, config files, etc.  Some have their own directory structure, some have everything in their root. I saw [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/289897/get-the-last-change-time-of-directory-recursively) and thought I could run that command inside a for loop, but I'm wondering if there's a more efficient way to write this using find and piping without just iterating over each folder in a loop. Ideas?

Comment: Don't make us chase links: please add the relevant info to this question.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly what you want, but the following meets what you seem to be asking:

```
find . -exec ls -db --full-time {} \; | sed -e 's/^[^ ]* [^ ]* [^ ]* [^ ]* [^ ]* //' -e 's/ [+-][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]//' | sort
```

Any other directory could of course be used in the `find`, for example `find /scripts/`.

Comment: @onbrokenwingz - thanks for the edit, correcting my over-hasty update.